# SQL String to get data from DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I decided to split the SQL Part away from [This Question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/235919/sql-to-excel-then-to-csv-file-for-data-upload).
Before we get started I need to let you know a critical piece of information: Due to permissions within an offsite database I am NOT allowed to create tables even temporary ones within the database that I am getting the data from.

With that being said: All of the code below works as expected, but I would like a review of it because I know that there has to be a cleaner way of writing the SQL String.

```
SELECT CONCAT(cfcif#,cfalta) AS Customer_Number,
                 cffna AS First_Name,
                 cfmna AS Middle_Name,
                 COALESCE(NULLIF(cflna,''),cfna1) AS Last_Name,                
                 COALESCE(NULLIF(RTRIM(LTRIM(cfpfa1))|| ' '|| RTRIM(LTRIM(cfpfa2)),''),RTRIM(LTRIM(cfna2),'')|| ' ' || RTRIM(LTRIM(cfna3),'')) AS Street_Address,
                 COALESCE(NULLIF(cfpfcy,''),cfcity) AS Street_City,
                 COALESCE(NULLIF(cfpfst,''),cfstat) AS Street_State,
                 COALESCE(NULLIF(LEFT(cfpfzc, 5), 0), LEFT(cfzip, 5)) AS Street_Zip,
                 CONCAT(RTRIM(LTRIM(cfna2)),RTRIM(LTRIM(cfna3))) AS Mailing_Address,
                 cfcity AS Mailing_City,
                 cfstat AS Mailing_State,
                 LEFT(cfzip, 5) AS Mailing_Zip,
                 NULLIF(cfhpho,0) AS Home_Phone,
                 NULLIF(cfbpho,0) AS Business_Phone,
                 NULLIF(cfssno,0) AS TIN,
                 (CASE 
                    WHEN cfindi = 'Y' THEN '1'
                    WHEN cfindi = 'N' THEN '2'
                   END) AS Customer_Type,
                 (CASE
                    WHEN cfdob7 = 0 THEN NULL
                    WHEN cfdob7 = 1800001 THEN NULL
                    ELSE cfdob7
                  END) AS Date_of_Birth,
                 cfeml1 AS Email_Address
    FROM bhschlp8.jhadat842.cfmast cfmast
    WHERE cfdead = 'N'
    ORDER BY cfcif#
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see much wrong with it.  Maybe use `BTRIM` if on Db2 11.1 or above rather than `RTRIM(LTRIM(` 
and maybe indent with fewer spaces (e.g. align the first column with the rest), but that is really a matter of style

Comment: unfortunately, i cant use `BTRIM`; I tried.  Also thats how the editor I use formats the string and im not a fan of it.  Thanks for taking a look at it.